# PrimeFaces and Jakarta EE 9.1 compatibility

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, tomcat10

What is the earliest version of PrimeFaces that works with Jakarta EE 9.1

Comment: Everything listed here: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces#versions